# Catalina: prevent auto sync iOS devices (globally)?

Tags: itunes, finder, catalina

Previously, in iTunes - Preferences - Devices, we can check 'Prevent iPods ... from syncing automatically'.

In Catalina, iOS device management has been Finder's job. I only found the switch per device. Is there a switch for all devices?